# Посимвольное чтение строки

Tags: c++, строки

Здравствуйте! Какими способами можно осуществить последовательное считывание символов из строки начиная с некоторой позиции. Пусть вектор содержит следующие строки-пути:

data/2016/E24G_2016037

data/2013/E30G_20130715

data/2012/E36G_20120311

data/2011/15G_20111203

Как из них можно прочесть двузначные числа, а именно 24, 30, 36 и 15 для дальнейшей записи в массив? Т.к. каждая строка содержит одинаковый символ "G", близ интересующих значений, я сумел лишь осуществить поиск его позиции. Любые предложения будут крайне полезными!

Пример:

```
std::vector<string>mydata;                          
void myClass::getNums()                     
{                                          
   int pos;        
   char nums[32];               
   for(int i=0; i<(int)mydata.size(); ++i)
   {
      pos=mydata[i].rfind("G");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что цифры двузначными не бывают :)

Если критерий - что они идут перед G - ну, что-то типа `while(isdigit(mydata[i][pos])) --pos;` - и вы становитесь на первую НЕ цифру, за которой идет интересующее вас число. Далее можно просто `atoi(mydata[i][pos+1])`, можно считывать и массой других вариантов...

Нужен точный критерий, что читать. Тогда можно даже регулярные выражения применить...

Comment: цифры таки бывают двузначными, да хоть трёхзначными. Всё зависит от основания системы счисления и используемого алфавита.

Comment: @vp_arth Приведите пример двузначной цифры

Comment: Допустим, `x0` в 4-ричной системе счисления с алфавитом `0,1,x0,x1`

Comment: @vp_arth  В такой системе счисления x0 и x1 - это один знак. От того, что вы используете вместо цифр слова - скажем, `четыре` - эта цифра не станет шестизначной. Вы путаете понятия... Цифра в принципе есть один знак - как бы вы его не записывали.

Comment: Ок, согласен. Двузначными не бывают)